# What is the best UI to override excluded values?

Tags: component, saas

I am working on a SaaS application where the user has set a list of values to be excluded from all records (let's call them global exclusions). This is a list of 7-10 string values.

When creating a new record, the user has the option to *override* the global exclusions. When this happens, the user would typically override 1-2 of the global exclusion values.

What would be the most appropriate UI to accomplish this?

**OPTION 1:** User activates the *Override global exclusions* toggle. A list of the global exclusion values appears. The user clicks the X to remove one. My concerns with this approach is:

- The user does not have context on which one was removed
- What if the user removed the wrong one by mistake? Should there be an undo/redo button?

**OPTION 2:** User activates the *Override global exclusions* toggle. A transfer list appears which shows the global exclusion values on the left column. The user can move the ones which they want to override to the right column. My concerns with this approach is confusion around the "exclusions" and "overrides" language. However, the user has context on what all values that are present.

[image]

Any other suggestions to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need them in a separate list? I'm not 100% sure if I fully understand the product, but from what I can tell, can you use Option 2 with only one list of checkboxes? It can be the list of all global exclusions and the user would select the ones that they want to override. You would have to change the title of the list to reflect that i.e. "Override global Exclusions" or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I may have been overthinking this. Using a single list with checkboxes may work.